# Use a valid integration method to calculate $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

We know that $f'(x)$ = $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ and $f(\pi/2)=0$, $f(3\pi/2)=1 $
Use a valid integration method to evaluate :
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}f(x)dx$$

i think $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx $ is the $f(x)$ function we're looking for, i used barrow theorem but i don´t know how to integrate it, any helps or hint will appreciate.

Comment: Then the problem is not correctly stated?

Comment: Isn't it $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, and $\int f'(x) \mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: I think so, but what can we do about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking and trying, i got the solution :

$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}f(x)dx $

Now we can use integration by parts, by it's definition , $u=f(x)$, $du=f'(x)dx$
and $dv=dx$, $v=x $,by ILATE rule :

\begin{align}
 =   f(x) x|_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}-\int xf'(x)dx                            \\
 & =\require{cancel} [\cancelto{1}{f(3\pi/2)}(3\pi/2)]-[\cancelto{0}{f(\pi/2)}(\pi/2)]-\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\cfrac {\cancel{x}\ cosx}{\cancel{x}}                             \\ 
 & = \Bigl(\cfrac{3\pi}{2}-0\Bigr)  -\ sen x|_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}                             \\
 & = \cfrac {3\pi}{2}-[(-1)-1]                             \\ 
 & =  \cfrac {3\pi}{2}+2                            \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

If your function is $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, and your task is to calculate
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}f'(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
Then you can use the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) to calculate the integral:
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}f'(x)\mathrm{d}x=f\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)-f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

$\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}
$,
also called
$sinc(x)
$
(sometimes with a $\pi$),
is not integrable
in finite terms.

It has been given a name:
$Si(x)
=\int_0^x \dfrac{sin(t)}{t}dt
$.

Special forms,
such as
$\int_0^{\infty}$
can be evaluated.

Your case can only be done
numerically.

Wolfy says
$Si((3 π)/2) - Si(π/2)≈0.23761058579952225576304433203202186890796018928024067084207168096967568361245277161035797838127400
$